# How to get horizontal recyclerview items to appear at the bottom of the recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My app currently looks like this:
[image]

How can I get these items to appear at the bottom of the screen? It may be worth noting that these items expand when selected.

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="292dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

Edit 1: Added the parent layout that the recycler view is contained inside of.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="99">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonAdd"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/buttonDelete"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Remove" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Edit" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="292dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the parent layout where recycler view in?

Comment: use relative layout as parent layout ;) just like @Wini suggest you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try implementing this in your layout :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</RelativeLayout>
```

similarly you can achieve it by linear layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="bottom">
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: How come linear layout doesnt work with bottom layout gravity?